# PhantomJS: getting "Killed: 9" for anything I'm trying

Tags: phantomjs, osx-yosemite

Just installed phantomjs, mac os x yosemite. Whenever I run /bin/phantomjs, with any parameter, I get `Killed: 9`. Any idea?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

re: running phantomjs on osx yosemite, download the build/fix found at:

https://github.com/eugene1g/phantomjs/releases

original issue:

https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12928

Comment: So basically it's not exactly this link above, but the link that is linked in the link above (lol) which is https://github.com/eugene1g/phantomjs/releases

Comment: Place extracted `phantomjs` script inside e. g. `/usr/local/bin` or other `$PATH` related folder.

Comment: Anyone know why this hasn't been merged into the main repo yet?

Answer (score 99):

1. Install UPX. UPX is an executable packer and unpacker

   ```
   $ brew install upx
   ```
2. Unpack the `phantomjs` executable

   ```
   $ upx -d phantomjs-2.0.0-macosx/bin/phantomjs
   ```
3. Run the `phantomjs` executable

   ```
   $ ./phantomjs-2.0.0-macosx/bin/phantomjs
   ```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly for me. 

@AndrewT. upx is an executable packer, running upx -d reverses the packing of the executable and restores it back to its original form (kind of like unzipping a file)

Comment: Note to others: your path to phantomjs might be different. I had been keeping my binary in /usr/bin/phantoms

Comment: This is the correct answer. The other should have its checkmark removed, and it should be put on this answer.

Comment: Works perfectly on OS 10.11

Comment: @Ram thanks, it works. but how? why do we need to unpack it?

Comment: There may be a bug in packaging script of Phantom.JS. Their documentation indicates that executables are packed only on Windows. Unfortunately, they are packed on Mac too. Please see: http://phantomjs.org/release-preparation.html.
    ```
    Pack phantomjs.exe with UPX:

    upx %PHANTOMJSDEPLOYDIR%\phantomjs.exe
Zip the contents of %PHANTOMJSDEPLOYDIR%.
    ```

Comment: If you've installed phantomjs 2 using brew cask install phantomjs, run upx -d /opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/phantomjs/2.0.0/phantomjs-2.0.0-macosx/bin/phantomjs

Comment: `$ brew install upx
Killed: 9`

Answer (score 2):

The eugene1g release and UPX install didn't work for me on El Capitan. What did work for me was installing PhantomJS using the phantomjs2 NPM package:

```
npm install phantomjs2

# Optional: symlink in a dir that's on my PATH:
ln -s /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phantomjs2/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
```

Answer (score 2):

`$ npm install -g phantomjs` worked for me on El Capitan.

The npm package isn't "official", it's maintained by a contributor, but it works. https://github.com/eugene1g/phantomjs

Answer (score 1):

## Blunt re-install using brew

Whatever is in `/usr/local/bin/phantomjs` has stopped working for you.

If you've got ~30mins to spare you can reinstall and relink using brew:

```
  # unlink old version
  brew unlink phantomjs

  # reinstall phantomjs
  brew update && brew install phantomjs

  # (You may wish to make a refreshing herbal tea or similar beverage here...)

  # Update link to usr/local/bin
  brew link --overwrite phantomjs
```

If you want to test what brew will do with `overwrite` you can run

```
 brew link --overwrite --dry-run phantomjs
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this happens when your current shell process is killed.

I was in `tmux` using `brew update`, and `brew` updated `tmux` and `bash`, then bang! Everything in `tmux` just returns `Killed: 9`.