# Install PhantomJS on MacOs 10.11 El Captian

Tags: javascript, macos, phantomjs, homebrew

I can't install phantomJs in my macbook after upgrading to 10.11 (El Capitan).

Whenever I try to install it using homebrew it gives me this error:

```
$ brew install phantomjs
phantomjs: OS X Yosemite or older is required.
Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.
```

Comment: You should take a look a the [Github issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/44525)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[Something is broken since Xcode 7](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/42249#issuecomment-142071357), if you have npm you can install it:

```
npm install -g phantomjs-prebuilt
```

---

Now that the issue have been handled, you can [download it](http://phantomjs.org/download.html).

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've finally installed it using npm

Comment: @jfcorugedo glad it helped :)

Comment: FYI... This npm installer is now called phantomjs-prebuilt.

Answer (score 19):

Note that :

```
npm install -g phantomjs
```

Will install `v1.9.8`

The latest preview version `v2.0.1` works correctly on 10.11 El Captian is [available as a binary download](https://github.com/Vitallium/phantomjs/releases/tag/2.0.1).

Just copy `bin/phantomjs` from the download into `/usr/local/bin/` (or wherever you want it) on your machine.

Comment: npm install -g phantomjs will install 2.1.1 as well

Answer (score 13):

```
brew update
```

then

```
brew install phantomjs
```

Comment: For me neither the brew nor downloaded from phantomjs.org 2.1 version is not working. I've been struggling all evening. After downgrading to 2.0 (downloaded from https://github.com/eugene1g/phantomjs/releases) everything is working. I'm using codeception with acceptance test on Mac Os Sierra.

Answer (score 6):

Install It through Homebrew or MacPorts

```
brew install phantomjs
```

or

```
port install phantomjs
```

Check the version using: `phantomjs --version`

Which will install the latest version. Currently: `2.1.1`

My Mac OSX version: `OS X El Capitan - Version 10.11.6`

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If that doesn't work try:

brew install npm

```
npm install phantom phantomjs -g
```

Answer (score 4):

The quickest and easiest way to install stand-alone phantomjs (tested on Mac OSX El Captian) (using brew or macports to install takes too long time since they will install the whole qt and other packages)

- download and unzip phantomjs-2.0.0-macosx.zip from http://phantomjs.org/download.html
- brew install upx
- upx -d phantomjs-2.0.0-macosx/bin/phantomjs

  - If you did not unpack phantomjs with upx, “killed -9” error occurs [PhantomJS: getting "Killed: 9" for anything I'm trying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267809/phantomjs-getting-killed-9-for-anything-im-trying)
- Add phantomjs to system path in Terminal: sudo nano /etc/paths
- echo $PATH
- add your_directory/phantomjs-2.0.0-macosx/bin to the end
- Hit control-x to quit.
- Enter “Y” to save the modified buffer.
- restart terminal
- Terminal: phantomjs -v will show you the version of phantomjs if it is correctly installed

Comment: thank you!  I downloaded the correct version i needed and was able to self install.

Comment: i download and move the phantomjs into /usr/local/bin.  works for me

Answer (score 4):

Latest released binary (2.1.1) for Mac has all the dependencies included in the binary. It works out of the box http://phantomjs.org/download.html