# how to install PhatntomJS in Mac ( El capitan )?

Tags: installation, phantomjs, osx-elcapitan

I see that PhantomJS offers support only till Yosemite. Is there any way to install that in El Capitan?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install PhantomJS on MacOs 10.11 El Captian](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33540903/install-phantomjs-on-macos-10-11-el-captian)

Answer (score 0):

try installing via npm

```
npm install -g phantomjs
```