# PhantomJS: curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found

Tags: php, curl, phantomjs

Tried installing phantomjs via brew, receive this error

> ==> Downloading https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/archive/2.
>       Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/phantomjs-2.0.0.tar.gz
>       ==> Downloading https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mikemcquaid/db645f7cbeec4f3b1b2e/raw/e664ecc5c259344d5a73a84b52e472bf8ad3733
>
> ```
> curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
> Error: Failed to download resource "phantomjs--patch"
> Download failed: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mikemcquaid/db645f7cbeec4f3b1b2e/raw/e664ecc5c259344d5a73a84b52e472bf8ad3733e/phantomjs-yosemite.patch
> ```

Answer (score 1):

**Installing PhantomJS on Ubuntu**

First, install or update to the latest system software.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential chrpath libssl-dev libxft-dev
```

Install these packages needed by PhantomJS to work correctly.

```
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev
sudo apt-get install libfontconfig1 libfontconfig1-dev
```

Get it from the PhantomJS website.

```
cd ~
export PHANTOM_JS="phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64"
wget https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/$PHANTOM_JS.tar.bz2
sudo tar xvjf $PHANTOM_JS.tar.bz2
```

Once downloaded, move Phantomjs folder to /usr/local/share/ and create a symlink:

```
sudo mv $PHANTOM_JS /usr/local/share
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/share/$PHANTOM_JS/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin
```

Now, It should have PhantomJS properly on your system.

phantomjs --version

Comment: Is there a Terminal/OS version of this?

Comment: Similar thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33540903/install-phantomjs-on-macos-10-11-el-captian